# How do you make case statements with ranges

Tags: shell, scripting, case

I'm supposed to:

Make a case statement that will display the a grade after input. With no loop or conditional.

> - A=90-100, B=80-89,  C=70-79,  D=60-69,  F=0-59

This is what I have so far:

```
    echo -n "What is your test score? (in percentage): "
    read percentage 

    case $name in 
    9?) echo "A" ;; 
    8?) echo "B" ;;
    7?) echo "C" ;;
    6?) echo "D" ;;
    5?) echo "F" ;;
    4?) echo "F" ;;
    3?) echo "F" ;;
    2?) echo "F" ;;
    1?) echo "F" ;;
    [0-9]) echo "F" ;;
    *) echo "Please enter another number" 
              read percentage 
    ;;
    esac
```

How do you just make a statement with the ranges (ex.  59-0)?

Comment: Check  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12616688/1742825) one. This is how you want to do it if you want to do using `case` statement itself.

Comment: @ramesh Do you think you can explain the pattern there in the case statement example you provided?

Comment: if you see the question of the answer I linked to, you could understand what the `case` statement means.

Comment: @Ramesh Yes I know what the meaning of a case statement is. If you're talking about the first answer we''re not not allowed to use if statements. And if you're talking about the second answer, I don't understand that shell pattern. Do you think you can explain it?

Comment: Dude, since this is an obvious homework question, let's ask this another way:  Have you got lecture notes on Shell Patterns and more Lecture Notes on Regex Expansion?  If so, read your notes on those two topics, and then study dogbane's answer.

Comment: @eyong100 No, we never learned shell patterns or Regex Expansion. That's why I'm still really confused about the code dogbane wrote. And yes, I have looked at examples online, and reviewed my notes.

Comment: @musicstrings `[x-y]` is the range of characters from `x` to `y`. This only applies to characters, so you can do `[0-9]`, but not `[101-110]`. `|` is `or`.  So `46[1-9]|4[7-9][0-9]` is 461 to 469, or 470 to 499.

Comment: this post answers for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614011/using-case-for-range-of-numbers-in-bash

Answer (score 3):

I would do this, it should satisfy the requirements.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "What is your test score? "
read score 

case $score in 
    100) echo "A" ;;
    9[0-9]) echo "A" ;; 
    8[0-9]) echo "B" ;;
    7[0-9]) echo "C" ;;
    6[0-9]) echo "D" ;;
    *) echo "F" ;;
esac
```

Initially I used 9[0-9]|100) but i think that violates the rule about conditionals.

It will return an F if you try entering 101 or any other "out of range" value. I made this assuming that this will never happen.

Comment: Conditional probably refers to `if` statements. The `|` in a case statement is not a conditional. It is a merely a pattern delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

This will also work-

```
echo -n "What is your test score? (in percentage): "
read per 

case $per in 
([9][0-9]|100) echo "A" ;; 
([8][0-9]) echo "B" ;;
([7][0-9]) echo "C" ;;
([6][0-9]) echo "D" ;;
[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]|59) echo "F" ;;
*) echo "Please enter another number" 
read percentage;;
esac
```

Comment: `|59` seems redundant